# Do we see through / in / behind/ by / from the window?

Tags: prepositions

What preposition goes with see something or someone behind the window in the following contex?

> I live in a villege,  and every morning when I get up,  I go to the window to look at the nature.  Yesterday when I did it,  I saw my best friend **through / in / behind/  by / from** the window,  coming to me.
>
> Believe me,  I saw you **through / in / behind/  by / from** the window yesterday,  but you were far to notice me.

Comment: I was at home,  and the friend was outside in the street.

Comment: In that case you saw your friend _from_  the window is the least ambiguous. Seeing your friend _through_ the window is also possible, but either of you could be in the street or inside the house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You see a person *through* the window when you are inside the room, the person is outside, and the window is closed (through the window's glass). It can also mean you are outside and looking inside, but for that, "behind" is more often used (see below).
- Seeing *from* the window means you are in the room, looking out, while the window is open (similar to "from the balcony").
- Seeing a person *in* the window suggests that you are outside and the person is inside, standing or sitting near the open window (like "in the frame").
- Seeing something *behind* the window suggests that you are outside while the thing is inside, and the window is closed (the object is behind the glass). This cannot be used when you are inside; in that case you see *through* the window.

In the example in your question, "from" seems most suitable, assuming the window is open (it is the distance that prevented the friend from seeing, not the window).